# Wrong parameter c# mvc 4

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I dont know what is happing but i send the number `1` as parameter with get method and when im debugging i get 0x00000001 as result

[image]

Here everything normal. Them I converted that get parameter to int to delete that entity but in the reciver method the result are kind of wrong??

[image]

I tried also with `int.Parse` but the same happened.

What is happening here?

Comment: I know but i cannot delete the entity but that value, or yes??

Comment: `0x000001 == 1`, up to the very last bit.

Answer (score 4):

In what way is it wrong? You've passed in "1" as a string, and your `id` variable has a value of 1. That number is the same whether it's represented as 1, 0x1, 00001, 0x00001 or anything similar. It's the same value. The debugger happens to be showing it to you in a zero-padded hex form, that's all.

It's very important to differentiate between data and some textual representation of that data, especially when in many cases there can be multiple textual representations of the same value. For example, consider these three lines:

```
int x = 0x10;
int x = 16;
int x = 0x000010;
```

Those are all *exactly* equivalent. They store a value of sixteen in a variable called `x`. By the time the code is compiled, there's no indication of which numeric literal form you happened to use in your source code.

Comment: but when i want to remove the entity, it cant find it. Why i say that? Because the entity its not being delete.

Comment: or can the entity interpretthe hex value and delete the entity?

Comment: @Ligth: Then you've presumably not got an entity with an ID of 1. That's a completely different matter, and without knowing anything about your entities or how you're deleting them, we can't help. But the value *is* 1.

Comment: Well i guest you are right, you cannt help if the entity if 1 or not.